# Schengen Visa of Poland (Multiple Entry)

Tags: schengen, multiple-entry, poland

I have been issued a 3 months validity Schengen visa of Poland with a stay of 30 days and it's a multiple entry visa.

My question here is, that on my very entry am I allowed to stay 30 days or the total stay of all entries in these 3 months should not exceed 30 days ?

Answer (score 6):

The total of all entries must not exceed 30 days.

The [Schengen Visa Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02009R0810-20160412), Annex VII:

> 4. ‘DURATION OF VISIT ... DAYS’ heading:
>
> This heading indicates the number of days during which the visa holder may stay in the territory for which the visa is valid. This stay may be continuous or, depending on the number of days authorised, spread over several periods between the dates mentioned under 2, bearing in mind the number of entries authorised under 3.
>
> The number of days authorised is written in the blank space between ‘DURATION OF VISIT’ and ‘DAYS’, in the form of two digits, the first of which is a zero if the number of days is less than 10.
>   The maximum number of days that may be entered under this heading is 90.
>
> When a visa is valid for more than six months, the duration of stays is 90 days in any 180-day period.

Comment: I dont think so, it should be of all entries, as i have confirmed with several people and according to my practical experience also it shouldnt be like that. Can you give me any page referral where it can be read?

Comment: @KartikAgarwal I do not understand your comment.  "Shouldn't be like" what?  Your visa allows you to spend 30 days in total in the Schengen area during the three-month period of the visa's validity.  I have linked to an HTML version of the Schengen visa code, is that referral not sufficient?

Comment: @KartikAgarwal many countries issue visas where the permitted duration of stay is for each entry.  Schengen visas don't work like that, however.

Comment: I totally appreciate your knowledge or the thing you are saying, i am not able to find for what i am looking for on that schengen visa code . Can you please help me where i can read it. And which countries issue visa where the permitted duration of stay is for each entry and which countries issue visa where it is for the all entries.

Comment: @KartikAgarwal the quoted material in the answer, in Annex VII paragraph 5, is where you can read it. Countries where the permitted duration is for each entry: I think some of the Australian visas work that way but I'm not sure I remember which ones.